# Parital derivative of sigmoid function with respect to theta

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, statistics, machine-learning

I am attempting to calculate the partial derivative of the sigmoid function with respect to theta:

$ y = \frac{1}{1+ e^{-\theta x}}$

Let:

$v = -\theta x $

$u = (1 + e^{-\theta x}) = (1 + e^v)$

Then:

$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = -u^{-2}$

$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} = e^v $

$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta_i} = -x_i $

So, applying the chain rule:

$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta_i} $

$= \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial \theta_i}$

$= -u^{-2} e^v (-x_i)$

$= -(1 + e^v)^{-2} e^v (-x_i)$

$= -(1+e^{-\theta x})^{-2} e^{-\theta x} (-x_i)$

$=\frac{-x_ie^{-\theta x}}{-(1+e^{-\theta x})^2} $

At this point, I'm trying to figure out how to get it into this form:

$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta_i} = y(1 - y)$

How do I accomplish this?

Also, it is alleged that:

$1 - \frac{1}{1+ e^{-\theta x}} = \frac{e^{-\theta x}}{1 + e^{-\theta x}}$

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that's actually possible. Best I can see, that derivative should be coming out to $xy(1-y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f(\theta)=\frac{1}{g(\theta)}=\frac{1}{1+e^{h(\theta)}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x}}.
$$
First, note that by the Chain rule
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime}(\theta) & =-g^{\prime}(\theta)/(g(\theta))^{2},\\
g^{\prime}(\theta) & =e^{h(\theta)}h^{\prime}(\theta),\\
\text{and }h^{\prime}(\theta) & =-x.
\end{align*}
Putting this all together,
$$
f^{\prime}(\theta)=-\frac{g^{\prime}(\theta)}{(g(\theta))^{2}}=-\frac{e^{h(\theta)}h^{\prime}(\theta)}{(g(\theta))^{2}}=\frac{e^{-\theta x}x}{(1+e^{-\theta x})^{2}}.
$$
Moreover, note that
$$
1-f(\theta)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x}}=\frac{1+e^{-\theta x}}{1+e^{-\theta x}}-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x}}=\frac{1+e^{-\theta x}-1}{1+e^{-\theta x}}=\frac{e^{-\theta x}}{1+e^{-\theta x}}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
f^{\prime}(\theta)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\theta x}}\frac{e^{-\theta x}}{1+e^{-\theta x}}x=f(\theta)\left(1-f(\theta)\right)x.
$$

Comment: In your last line, you still have an $x$ in the numerator that isn't present in the value of $1-f(\theta)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Good catch; that was a mistake on my part. I guess the $x$ is there to stay. Perhaps the question wanted OP to write it in the form $f(\theta)(1-f(\theta))$ for $x=1$? (since, otherwise, it is simply not true)